# cannot use cookies in cURL PHP

Tags: php, curl, session-cookies

I'm using cURL to parse a website.

> http://www.hcmiu.edu.vn/bookforsale/showbooks.php

It need session to view, if you don't have session then the page redirect to :

> http://www.hcmiu.edu.vn/bookforsale/perInfo.php

I use this code to get session cookie but I don't know why I cannot see any change to file cookies.txt

```
$urltopost = "http://www.hcmiu.edu.vn/bookforsale/perInfo.php";
$datatopost = array (
"name" => "abc",
"tel" => "99999999",
"email" => "abc@gmail.com",
"profession" => "abc",
"employer" => "abc",
"tel_work" => "99999999",
); 
$ch = curl_init($urltopost);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $datatopost);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "/tmp/cookies.txt"); 

$returnData = curl_exec($ch);
$file = fopen("example.txt", "w");
fwrite($file, $returnData);
fclose($file);
curl_close($ch);
```

However, I see:

```
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=1egb993objkrdp3gi5mpvs02g0; path=/
```

in the header. Thanks for any help

-Edit:
I use a tricky way: I use http viewer to view the PHPSESSID in browser cookies. And then I use it to to create a cookies file for cURL to read. Then I could pass the session checking of the web server for viewing file showbooks.php .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used this code snippet to extract the cookie from the server's response:

```
$returnData = curl_exec($ch);
$cookie = '';
$pattern = '/Set-Cookie:(.*?)\n/';
if (preg_match($pattern, $returnData, $result))
$cookie = $result[1];
```

I've described my experience in [this post](http://kniganapolke.wordpress.com/2009/10/08/form-autorization-curl-php/). This approach doesn't use cookie file.

---

What concerns **cookie file**, consider the following advice from http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php:

> Use absolute path for setting the
>   variables CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE &
>   CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR. To make life easier
>   use the realpath("file.txt") function
>   to get the absolute path.

Comment: thanks, your solution help me a lot. I don't know why some tutorials on internet does not comment about this problem.

Answer (score 2):

is the file writable? does it even exist?

Comment: the file is unexisted. But if it's existed, it also isn't written any cookies data.

Answer (score 2):

Try creating the file and give it global read write privilege.

Also try with a relative path (say, ./cookies.txt) instead of an absolute path for the cookie jar file.