# Why php curl does not save cookie in my cookiefile?

Tags: php, cookies, curl, cookiejar

I'm trying to save a cookie in the curl cookiejar. I've simplified my code but its not working.

```
<?php

$cookie_file = './cookies.txt';

if (! file_exists($cookie_file) || ! is_writable($cookie_file)){
    echo 'Cookie file missing or not writable.';
    exit;
}//cookie_file is writable, so this is not the issue

$ch = curl_init (html_entity_decode("http://localhost/kiala_test/setcookie.php"));
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
$output = curl_exec ($ch);
echo $output;
?>
```

setcookie.php

```
<?php 
$value = 'something from somewhere';
setcookie("TestCookie", $value);

?>
```

received header

> HTTP/1.1 200 OK Date: Thu, 10 Oct 2013 12:10:37 GMT Server:
>   Apache/2.4.4 (Win64) PHP/5.4.12 X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.12 Set-Cookie:
>   TestCookie=something+from+somewhere Content-Length: 0 Content-Type:
>   text/html

so the testcookie is in the header but my cookiefile stays empty. What I'm doing wrong? what can I try to make this example work? thank you!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

When setting `CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR`, you need to use an absolute path. You can do this easily by using:

```
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, realpath($cookie_file) );
```

Reference: [cannot use cookies in cURL PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3852750/cannot-use-cookies-in-curl-php)

Comment: thank you! I've been struggling with this for a few hours now, even tried absolute paths but it wasn't working. realpath did the trick. thank you again.

Comment: `realpath` returns absolute path, so you were doing something wrong, when you were struggling with this.

Comment: CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR absolute path is required only for Windows platform. In Linux/Unix path can be relative. I checked it.

Answer (score 1):

As [reference](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) about `CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR`:

> The name of a file to save all internal cookies to when the handle is closed, e.g. after a call to curl_close.

So, in your code didn't used `curl_close`.

Use `curl_close($ch);` after `curl_exec`, for save cookies in jar file.

Answer (score 1):

Yes realpath works, but remember that (thanks to php.net) before second call of curl_exec, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE should be the same as in previous setting of CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR - because it is used for reading from "jared" file :)

```
//my working snippet for one php file:
//....
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, realpath('test2-cookie.txt'));
$content = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch); 
$ch = curl_init();  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, realpath('test2-cookie.txt'));
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, realpath('test2-cookie.txt'));
$content = curl_exec($ch);//second call
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried every thing and the what's worked for me was putting the absolute path for cookies file

```
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, '/var/www/myapp/cookies.txt' ); 
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, '/var/www/myapp/cookies.txt' );
```